# JDBC - select where column is NULL

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jdbc

I have a simple table in my Postgres 9.0 database:

```
create table test (id int not null, value int);
```

I have populated it with a few rows:

```
insert into test values (1, 1);
insert into test values (2, null);
insert into test values (3, null);
insert into test values (4, 1);
```

Now I'm trying to read it with JDBC. When I select by the non-null values in the `value` column, everything is fine:

```
PreparedStatement select = c.prepareStatement("select * from test where value=?");
select.setInt(1, 1);
return select.executeQuery();
```

But when I want to select rows where `value` is null, the Result Set contains no rows. I have tried both of these approaches:

```
select.setObject(1, null);
```

and

```
select.setNull(1, Types.INTEGER);
```

Neither work!

What's going on? I know that the correct SQL to check for NULLs would be `where value is null` instead of `where value=null` but surely JDBC is clever enough to sort that out for me?

Comment: No, JDBC is not clever enough. Bad luck.

Comment: If JDBC would do that, it would be violating valid behavior specified by the SQL standard

Comment: The behaviour of "= null" is not the same on other db systems. Sometimes writing " = null" and "is null" is the same. In Sybase and MS SQL i think. And that makes things really complicated if you have different db types for your application.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Nothing is `= NULL`. If you typed `select * from test where value=NULL` into an interactive query evaluator, you'd get nothing back. JDBC doesn't rewrite your expression, it just substitutes in the values.

You have to use a query using the `is` operator instead:

```
PreparedStatement select = c.prepareStatement("select * from test where value is NULL");
return select.executeQuery();
```

You've said you expect JDBC to be "clever" enough to do that for you, but that would be a big violation of the separation of concerns. You may well *want* to have a parameter in your query using `=` which you set `NULL` knowing that that relation will never evaluate true (as part of a larger set of conditions, most likely).

Comment: Thanks - in the end I needed to write a comparison function which takes 2 args, and returns true if they are equal or if they are both null.

Answer (score 0):

you can use below as a string and compare the DB value with NULL

```html
 String formatType="SomeValue";
 String BuildingName = "Some Value";
 String floor = "SomeValue";

 String query = "SELECT pd.*\n" +
                "FROM PROPERTY_DETAIL pd\n" +
                "WHERE pd.FORMAT_TYPE = '"+formatType+"'\n" +
                "  AND (pd.BUILDING_NAME = '"+BuildingName+"' OR (pd.BUILDING_NAME IS NULL))\n" +
                "  AND (pd.FLOOR = '"+floor+"' OR (pd.FLOOR IS NULL))";

DBConnection.executeSQLQuery(query);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your query a bit.

```
select * from test 
where (value is null or value = ?) // for optional cols that can be null
and value2 = ? // for cols that are never null

param    detailed                        result
null     value is null or value = null   will be true 
5        value is null or value = 5      will be true
```