# Delete use setNull don't work

Tags: java, jdbc

I want to delete DB where column is null and use preparedstatement
This is my code

```
String deletesql = "delete from user where e-mail = ?";
PreparedStatement prestmt = conn.prepareStatement(deletesql);
prestmt.setNull(1,Types.VARCHAR);
prestmt.executeUpdate();
```

But these code don't work

Comment: why it not work, it throw and exception or what?

Comment: @YCF_L It won't work because `something = null` is unknown (or null).

Comment: mmm, thank you @MarkRotteveel :)

Answer (score 2):

please try it with

```
String deletesql = "delete from user where e-mail is null";
```

If something is unknown (NULL) it is not equal to something else(`=`)

Answer (score 2):

In SQL `something = null` is unknown, you need to use `something is null`, or in the case of parameters `something is ?` and use `setNull(1, Types.NULL)`.

If you want to have both null and non-null values you need to make it a little more complicated:

```
(something is ? or something = ?)
```

or even (the previous might not work on all databases):

```
(? is null and something is null or something = ?)
```

And then use:

```
if (something == null) {
   stmt.setNull(1, Types.NULL);
   // NOTE: check behavior of your db, some might require a non-null value here
   stmt.setXxxx(2, null);
} else {
   // Setting a null-type parameter to a non-null value should mark it as not null
   stmt.setObject(1, "not null", Types.NULL);
   // Use appropriate setter
   stmt.setXxxx(2, something);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/19836582
You'd have to use a statement like "DELETE WHERE e-mail IS NULL" and omit the "setNull" call. Probably you'd like to put that into a separate prepared statement cause that only works for NULL columns.