# IS NOT NULL in PreparedStatement

Tags: java, jdbc

I have a dynamic query as shown below, the operator 'is' using for null or not null in DB2 Query. If I use below code, Verascan finding issue and it stops approval. We need to use query parameters for all conditions. I can do query parameter for NULL with setObject or setNull, but how to do query param for NOT NULL in Java JDBC? This is a DB2 query.

```java
if (operators != null && i < operators.length &&   
    operators[i].toUpperCase().trim().startsWith("IS"))  
{         
    result.append(" ")
          .append(operators[i])
          .append(" ")
          .append(validate(filterValues[i]));     
}
```

Comment: So your question is about how to get around the VERA check, right? Not about the query itself

Comment: Thank you Jorn for quick response, my question is how can we set not null in prepared statement... ps.setNull() or ps.setObject() will be used for setting the null in ps, similarly how can we set not null to ps. but if there is a work around to get off from vera check, that would be great.

Comment: There's no programmatic way to compare `IS (NOT) NULL`, so there's nothing to do but supress the warning.

Comment: Thanks @Kayaman, my team implemented work around solution for this, we have hard coded the value null instead of taking values from user if operatior is or is not

Comment: Yeah, I don't know why JDBC can't handle it for us, [some say it's a feature](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19836582/2541560), so everyone ends up writing their own translation to `(NOT) NULL`.